# Custom font Xcode 4.6 using storyboard

Tags: xcode4.6

I have added Imago font (including bold, italic and those both with those names: boolta, med and medlta) to Info.plist, but now I'm totally stuck with several tutorials.

I'm using storyboard mode.

Could someboby tell me what codes I have to write and where to get these font to work?

Answer (score 1):

been having a lot of issues with fonts myself recently and there are a few things I suggest checking: -

1/ Always use .ttf format

2/ Make sure your font is included in 'Copy Bundle Resources' in your project 'Build Phases'

3/ Custom fonts should be defined in the array in your '[appname]-Info.plist' like you said above, it's under the heading 'Fonts provided by application'

4/ Make sure that you are using the correct font name as it is usually different to the filename.  To get a list of available font names use the below code.  Just using finders 'Get Info' is not always reliable: -

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]){
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family]){
        NSLog(@"font=%@", name);
    }
}
```

Then use the font name outputted in your log

5/ If that STILL doesn't work, it may mean your font encoding is a little messed up.  I had this recently with a .ttf font, the app just couldn't see it so I stuffed the file [into this online converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) and whatever the issue was disappeared, magic!